# What is the fastest/preferred way to store static data in android?

Tags: android

I want to store around a thousand strings (like some quotes) and populate a `ListView` or `ListFragment` using them. These strings are static and not likely to change once loaded.

It is a read-only data and user should not be allowed to manipulate it.

Should i store them using XML file or a text file, or what could be the best approach?

Comment: use a sqlite database

Comment: Do these Strings change at runtime? And do you need people with no access to the source to be able to edit them?

Comment: Strings won't change at runtime. I won't like users to edit them as well. Just a kind of read-only stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Use Sqlite db thats the efficient and secure way

Comment: But if user accidentally deletes the database, would it not cause any issues? Could you please elaborate more on why Sqlite only as am not clear on it.

Comment: Only a rooted user would be able to delete the database, because it is stored in the protected directory of the app. Using a database has a few advantages over the other mentioned methods: it has optimized queries that allow you to easily implement filters and such things for your list view. It also doesn't require you to store all of the strings in memory.

Comment: But you can't query `SharedPreferences` the way you can query a SQLite database

Comment: As Thrakbad said,database cant deleted unless u hav root access or removed it through your code,within your same app.so dont worry about that ,thats why i used the term secure

Comment: But if user accidentally deletes the app, would it not cause any issues? Could you please elaborate more on why Sqlite only as am not clear on it.

Comment: User can't accidentally delete an app. He can uninstall with confirmation. Sqlite storage for the app is pnly accessible by itself. In your case your can write a copy of DB (Encrypted) to the external storage if you need access after uninstall and reinstall the app.

Answer (score 2):

Shared Prefrences is the best way to store small data. [You Can take help from this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the data are not going to change in the entire application development why u not going for **static final** way using with any **access modifier** as u like and u can use them in your application and as size concern thousand or lakh of String data is not going to effect as we know also String is **immutable** and can't change throughout the app life and one more thing with  declaring as **final** so reinitialize will not be there but only reusing.Declare all the string in the as the class part so it load when class load i.e. once.If any more thing let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It will never change?

String data type?

Do you have them already when building the app?

Simply save them in Resources, strings; just like you store values like 'appname'
You can save one huge string variable separated by line breaks (or commas, colons, etc) , then use java's string utilities or tokenize to get each substring, or anything you seem fit according to the patter it has

Comment: Yes, i will have them during developing itself. Your idea sounds good, but just one doubt, will it be efficient to store thousand of them like that?

Comment: Well I'd consider that getResources() will load all the variable in memory. If that's an issue you need to segregate in multiple files and load only the ones you really need - if able.
But then again, one thousand words is a few Kb.. if your strings are wordsefficiency won't be an issue

Answer (score 0):

Just put them in a text file which you store in the assets folder. If you put them line by line you have already your items.